# Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from Temporal Accessor when parsing localDateTime. I am trying to get rid of months less than 30days

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
DateTimeFormatter fm = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("MMMuuuu")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2021)
            .toFormatter(Locale.US);
         
          List<LocalDate> datesMoreThan30 = new ArrayList<>();
          List<LocalDate> datesLessThan30 = new ArrayList<>();
          String fromDate = from;
          String toDate = to;
         
          LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(fromDate,fm);
          LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse(toDate,fm);
         
          long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
         
          if(days >= 30) {
                 datesMoreThan30.add(date1);
                 datesMoreThan30.add(date2);
                
          }
          else if(days < 30) {
                 datesLessThan30.remove(date1);
                 datesLessThan30.remove(date2);
         
          }
```

below is the error I keep getting.

```
3:21:31.183 [http-nio-8088-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jan2021' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=1, Year=2021},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed] with root cause
java.time.DateTimeException:
```

Comment: can you show some input output example, sorry i didn't get your question

Comment: Why do you mention “localDateTime” in the title?

Answer (score 4):

You have used `ChronoField.YEAR` instead of `ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH` for `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`.

**Demo with correct `ChronoField`:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter fm = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("MMMuuuu")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                                .toFormatter(Locale.US);
        
        String fromDate = "Jan2021";
        LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, fm);
        System.out.println(date1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RmvmmV)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

A date consists of 3 fields: `YEAR`, `MONTH_OF_YEAR`, and `DAY_OF_MONTH`.

Your pattern requires the text to have a `MONTH_OF_YEAR` (`MMM`) and a `YEAR` (`uuuu`), but has no day value (`d` or `dd`).

For unknown reasons, you give a default `YEAR`, even though the pattern *requires* a year, so that default is meaningless. You don't give a default `DAY_OF_MONTH`, so there is not enough information to build a date.

*Solution 1*

Change the code to specify the default `DAY_OF_MONTH`:

```java
DateTimeFormatter fm = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("MMMuuuu")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("Jan2021", fm);
System.out.println(date); // 2021-01-01
```

*Solution 2*

Parse to a `YearMonth`, and supply the dayOfMonth in Java code:

```java
DateTimeFormatter fm = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMuuuu", Locale.US);

YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("Jan2021", fm);
LocalDate date = ym.atDay(1);
System.out.println(date); // 2021-01-01
```